# Evitar pérdidas de datos al dar actualizar o al presionar la tecla F5

Tags: php, mysql

Necesito que cuando le de actualizar a la página, no se me borren los datos.

Este es el código:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include "conectar.php";
//echo 'id_inspeccion'.$_SESSION['id_inspeccion'];
$Odt                = addslashes($_POST['Odt']);
```

Uso el método [POST]

HTML:

```
<div class="col-sm-2 form-group">
  <label class="control-label">ODT No </label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtFormulario_Odt">
</div>
```

Comment: cuales datos?...

Comment: los datos del formulario puse un ejemplo de mi html y un ejemplo de como los mando

Comment: Agrega el dato en el atributo value del tag input usando el htmlspecialchar() - para evitar inyeccion de javascript-

Comment: no entendi la verdad amigo